# How can I do this with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana

I was writing a PHP (Kohana) app and I saw that the controller index pages could be seen with & without /index.

http://plugb.com/ & http://plugb.com/index

In order to avoid duplicated content, I did this:

```
$clean_url = str_replace('index','',$this->request->uri);

if($clean_url !== $this->request->uri)
{
 $this->request->redirect($clean_url);
}
```

I would like to know how to do the same, but with .htaccess.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a nitpick, that `str_replace()` should probably be a `preg_replace()` with the `$` anchor. You never know when you may need that substring in your URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index($|/(.*))$ /$2 [L,R=301]
```

This rule will remove any leading `/index` from the URL path.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but I suspect this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index$ $1 [L,R=301]
```